# How to use phloc schematron-pure with Document -schema-definition

Tags: schematron

This question concerns [phloc-schematron](https://code.google.com/p/phloc-schematron/wiki/FirstStepsJava), a library for ISO Schematron validation.

I am creating schematron-files on the fly, so I have them available as document (or as string of course)

I cannot find a constructor for SchematronResourcePure that takes a string or document as argument, nor can I find a method to create a IReadableResource from the same.

Can someone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is still relevant:
Switch to ph-schematron at https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron/ and use the static SchematronResourcePure.fromString method.

But you are right - this is a case that is currently not considered - building the Schematron from scratch. I will see, what I can do!